# Collecting dictionaries from loop into a single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Hello I've got the following loop that produces a dictionary as output:

```
for l in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = (l.get('href'))
    if link.count('2021') == 1:
        stuff = urllib.parse.urlsplit(link)
        stuff = stuff.path.split('/')
        list(stuff)
        if stuff[1] == '2021':
            stuff = np.array(stuff)
            year = stuff[1]
            month = stuff[2]
            day = stuff[3]
            category = stuff[4]
            keywords = stuff[5:7]
            dict = {'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day, 'category': category, 'keywords': keywords}
```

The output look like that:

```
/Users/Programowanie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/bin/python /Users/Programowanie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
   year month day category                               keywords
0  2021    09  02       us  supreme-court-texas-abortion-law.html
   year month day category                               keywords
0  2021    09  02       us  supreme-court-texas-abortion-law.html
   year month day category                               keywords
0  2021    09  02       us  supreme-court-texas-abortion-law.html
   year month day category                       keywords
0  2021    09  02       us                       politics
1  2021    09  02       us  biden-abortion-texas-law.html
   year month day category                       keywords
0  2021    09  02       us                       politics
1  2021    09  02       us  biden-abortion-texas-law.html
```

I would like to sort all separate dictionaries into one single DataFrame so that the values for year, month, day, category, keywords are saved in the corresponding columns year, month, day, category, keywords. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pd.concat(output)` assuming `output` is your list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you init an empty `pd.DataFrame` and for each iteration you append the value with this expression `df.loc[len(df)] = dict_`

This example:
(should works as is)

```
dict_ = {
    'year': '2021',
    'month': '09',
    'day': '02',
    'category': 'us',
    'keywords': 'supreme-court-texas-abortion-law.html'
}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['year', 'month', 'day', 'category','keywords'])
for x in range(10):
    df.loc[len(df)] = dict_

print(df)
```